# How to save adb reverse or adb forward configurations?

Tags: android, adb

Is there any way to save my `adb reverse` or `adb forward` configurations?

Or I need to type `adb reverse tcp:3000 tcp:3000` every time I run the android emulator?

I have an shell script to do this but it doesn't seem right... is there other way?